# no case clause matching: :empty error in changeset for cast_attachments for file upload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following model and for images I am using Arc module for upload

> defmodule Chemical.Info do
>       use Chemical.Web, :model
>
> ```
> schema "infos" do
>     field :title, :string
>     field :shortdesc, :string
>     field :longdesc, :string
>     field :images, Chemical.ImageUploader.Type
>     field :regions, :string
>     field :startdate, :date
>     field :enddate, :date
>     field :status, :string
>     field :createdby, :string
>     field :approvedby, :string
>
>     timestamps()
> end
>
> @required_fields ~w(title shortdesc startdate enddate )
> @optional_fields ~w(longdesc regions status createdby approvedby)
> @required_file_fields ~w()
> @optional_file_fields ~w(images)
>
>    def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
>     model
>
>     |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
>     |> cast_attachments(params, @required_file_fields, @optional_file_fields )
>
> end
> ```
>
> end

new function in controller

> ```
> def new(conn, _params) do
>     changeset = Info.changeset(%Info{})
>     render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
> end
> ```

I am getting the following error in cast_attachments function call when accessing the /new action which returns new form

> no case clause matching: :empty

If I remove the cast_attachments line, it shows the new form.
Arc version is 0.6.0 and arc_ecto is 0.5.0. 
I am using local storage so the default uploader generated by Arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ecto 2.0, passing `:empty` as `params` is deprecated in favor of an empty map (`%{}`). It looks like arc_ecto 0.5.0 doesn't allow sending `:empty` anymore already instead of issuing warning. You need to change `:empty` to `%{}` as the default value of `params`:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
```

->

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
```